# Quarkus Interceptor on private methods

Tags: java, logging, methods, quarkus, interceptor

Is it possible to add a quarkus interceptor on a private method? I would like to log the time the method takes and want to use an interceptor i have for this purpose. It works fine on all public methods and doesn't on the private method.

Answer (score 3):

By design interceptors work only for `public`, `protected` and `package-private` (default visibility) methods.
During Quarkus deployment any interceptor on private methods is just ignored but should leads to a a failed build if [this property](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#quarkus-arc_quarkus.arc.fail-on-intercepted-private-method) is setted.
Quarkus allows [interception of non-private static method](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#interception-of-static-methods)

Comment: In fact, CDI interceptors work for `public`, `protected` and package-private (default visibility) methods. But you're right that an interceptor binding declared on a private method either results in a build failure or is simply ignored.

Comment: Just edited with @MartinKouba corrections